# How to save cookies for my android web application

Tags: android, cookies, webview

lets say I have an application for my University web site. Where user can navigate by pressing on screen button( Actually, what I did, I categorized everything in my main layout,where each button represents each fields, if any one presses myaccountStatus, then he will be directed to that specific link) However, my web site needs user name and password every time. Where I don't want my user to bother about this at all. So my question is, is there any way I can enable auto-log in?

My application has basic core web feature implemented(WebView, zoom, java-script enabled, some back, forward, stop, reload, favorite, save for offline reading) and everything is working fine, please help with the auto-log in problem.

So far I know, I can do this by saving cookies. But I have no Idea, how they look, what are they and how to handle those thing. So, please give me a step by step tutorial for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using a web-view based approach (maybe something like cordova?) you could just use the local storage or the web sql standard for html5 apps: [Tutorial for Web-Sql](http://tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm).

If you want to store cookies you have to enable them. I'm doing this in my Phonegap/Cordova application with this small Lines of code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ... do whatever you want...
// this lines allow to set cookies  
    try {
        CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
    }
    // and the default stuff for phonegap/cordova to show a splashscreen and load the application
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    // load the index url from config adding locale support.
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl() + "?locale="
            + Locale.getDefault().getLanguage(), 4000);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: let me try this!! And thanks a lot.!! One more can you please tell me, is that possible to share cookies with some other application?

Comment: @androCoder-BD Cookies cannot be shared between applications, unless you manually retrieve the cookie and then send it to another app. Cookies are stored in the /data folder of your app which is unreachable by other apps.